rm/mv commands sometimes hang (Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS)
I don't know why this keeps happening but I run a program that is constantly creating and removing small files and occasionally the rm would hang. I then switched to using mv since I noticed it ran a lot faster but same problem. See the following screenshot for an actual example. Note no other process has that file locked or opened. But if I touch the file, then it "unsticks" the rm/mv command and it runs instantly.  The /mnt/ramdisk/ (despite the name) is just a 8GB hdd (/dev/sdc1), as shown below.
$ df /mnt/ramdisk5
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1        8152540 2022108   5694720  27% /mnt/ramdisk5
$ df -i /mnt/ramdisk5
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      524288 191565 332723   37% /mnt/ramdisk5



Is the delay the disk winding up?

definitely not since it's virtual machine and the backing storage is nvme ssd on pcie card
